# Are Intersection over Union (IoU) scores preferring larger objects?

Tags: deep-learning

According to the fcn model I implemented and the PASCAL VOC benchmark [(here)](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk:8080/leaderboard/displaylb.php?cls=mean&challengeid=11&compid=6&submid=15347#KEY_FCN-8s-heavy)
I find that objects with larger sizes in an image receive better IoU or AP score in the test set. Why do the IoU scores have a bias towards larger scale objects? Can anyone give an explanation why this could happen？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons for this behaviour:

- **training data:** In your training data, there could be more larger objects than smaller objects, so the model didn't have enough information about smaller objects to learn to segment them well.
- **training procedure:** Depending on your training procedure (e.g. loss function), your model will focus more on some type of objects (in your case, larger objects ...)
- **model architecture:** Every model has some advantages, so some models are better in recognizing objects of various sizes. E.g.  convolutional and pooling layers can increase a receptive field of neurons so that they could recognize objects of various sizes more easily. Also, some model architectures are specialized in recognizing models of varying sizes.

Possible directions:

- **training data:** Know your data! :) Inspect the dataset to see what's in. The things to look for: are all classes represented well, are labels (ground truth) good, sizes of objects, ...
- **training procedure:** Try with various loss functions (cross entropy, dice loss, cross entropy + dice loss, focal loss, ...). Also, dataset augmentation techniques are important (e.g. with dataset augmentation you can create objects of various sizes ...).
- **model architecture:** Resnet, Inception, InceptionResnet - those are the backbones that you might want to use for your backbone as they have proved to be good for semantic segmentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since small object has less pixels , a small bias in numbers of predicted pixels will cause the iou error. Could this be the reason that cause the better performance on large object ?

Comment: Yes, that also could be the reason.